# Navigating to state replaces the index ui-view with state's component, instead of named ui-view inside of parent's template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state-management

**Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/TrjrZ4vQlOjxyjc1mKQt?p=preview**

#### Expected

After <kbd>Login</kbd> selecting a Ticker should display the Tags list to the right of the Ticker list in an orange area called Tags scope.

*How the app should look like*

[image]

---

#### Results

Selecting a Ticker will activate the Tags state, however the Tags template will replace the top level index ui-view. Instead of rendering the Tags template inside of the `<div ui-view="tags@tickers"></div>` in the Tickers template.

*How the app looks like*

[image]

[image]

### Architecture

After Login, you are sent to the `container` state which has 2 views: `dashboard` and `feed`.

I feel that my problem is that I'm not activating a `dashboard state` nor am I activating a `tickers state` if so how can I do that in my current architecture?

---

```
// Container module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var container = angular.module('container', [ 'ui.router' ])
  container.config(function($stateProvider) {
    const container = {
      name: 'container',
      url: '/container',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'container-template.html',
          controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('CONTAINER view $state');
          }
        },
        'dashboard@container': {
          templateUrl: 'dashboard-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('DASHBOARD view $state', $state);
          }
        },
        'feed@container': {
          templateUrl: 'feed-template.html',
          controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('FEED view $state');
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    $stateProvider.state(container);
  });
```

The Dashboard template

```
<div class="dashboard-state">
  <div class="fl w100">
    <em>Dashbaord scope</em>  
  </div>
  
  <!--<div ui-view="tickers"></div>-->
  <tickers-module></tickers-module>
</div>
```

The Tickers component

```
tickers.component('tickersModule', {
  templateUrl: 'tickers-template.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    console.log('TICKERS component');
    $scope.tickers = [
      { id: 1, ticker: 'AAPL' },
      { id: 2, ticker: 'GOOG' },
      { id: 3, ticker: 'TWTR' }
    ];
    
    $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
      console.log(' Ticker clicked!', $state)
      $state.go('tags', { ticker: ticker }); // <~~~~ Action to go to Tags
    }
  }
});
```

Tickers template

```
<div class="tickers-state">
  <div class="fl w100">
    <em>Tickers scope</em>    
  </div>

  <div class="tickers-panel">
    <div class="tickers-list">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="ticker in tickers" class="fl">
          <button ng-click="clickTicker(ticker)">{{ ticker.ticker }}</button>
        </li>
      </ul>      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div ui-view="tags@tickers"></div>
  <!--<tags-module></tags-module>-->
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/CFbkPAlL2kVMSM3G4q5T?p=preview

Got it working by properly using child states!

Needed to name states like so to let the app know what the parent is:

```
const dashboard = {
    name: 'container.dashboard',
    views: {
        'dashboard': {
            template: '<dashboard-module></dashboard-module>'
        },
        'feed': {
          templateUrl: 'feed-template.html',
          controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('FEED STATE');
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when navigating states, the naming convention helped with specificity

```
$scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
  console.log(' >>> ticker view state', ticker)
  $state.go('container.dashboard.tickers.tagslist', { ticker: ticker });
}
```

And proper use of named views:

```
const tags = {
  name: 'container.dashboard.tickers.tagslist',
  url: '/tags',
  params: {
    ticker: {}
  },
  views: {
    'tags' : {
```

### Full Code

```
// Container module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var container = angular.module('container', [ 'ui.router' ])
  container.config(function($stateProvider) {

    const container = {
      name: 'container',
      url: '/container',
      templateUrl: 'container-template.html',
      controller: function($scope, $state) {
        console.log('CONTAINER STATE');
        // $state.go('dashboard', {});
      }
    }

    const dashboard = {
        name: 'container.dashboard',
        // deepStateRedirect: true,
        // sticky: true,
        views: {
            'dashboard': {
                template: '<dashboard-module></dashboard-module>'
            },
            'feed': {
              templateUrl: 'feed-template.html',
              controller: function($scope) {
                console.log('FEED STATE');
              }
            }
        }
    }

    $stateProvider
      .state(container)
      .state(dashboard);
  });

// Dashboard module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var dashboard = angular.module('dashboard', [ 'ui.router' ])

    dashboard.config(function($stateProvider) {
      const dash_default = {
        name: 'container.dashboard.default',
        url: '/dashboard',
        template: '<tickers-module></tickers-module>',
        controller: function() {
          console.log(' DASHBOARD.DEFAULT STATE')
        }
      }
      $stateProvider.state(dash_default);
    })

    dashboard.component('dashboardModule', {
    templateUrl: 'dashboard-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('DASHBOARD component');
    }
  });

// Tickers module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var tickers = angular.module('tickers', ['ui.router'])

  tickers.config(function($stateProvider) {

    const tickers = {
      // parent: 'dashboard',
      name: 'container.dashboard.tickers',
      url: '/tickers',
      params: {
        ticker: {}
      },
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'tickers-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log(' TICKERS STATE', $state);

            $scope.tickers = [
              { id: 1, ticker: 'AAPL' },
              { id: 2, ticker: 'GOOG' },
              { id: 3, ticker: 'TWTR' }
            ];

            // $state.go('tags', { ticker: $scope.tickers[0] });

            $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
              console.log(' >>> ticker view state', ticker)
              $state.go('container.dashboard.tickers.tagslist', { ticker: ticker });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $stateProvider.state(tickers);
  })
  tickers.component('tickersModule', {
    templateUrl: 'tickers-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('TICKERS component');
      // $scope.tickers = [
      //   { id: 1, ticker: 'AAPL' },
      //   { id: 2, ticker: 'GOOG' },
      //   { id: 3, ticker: 'TWTR' }
      // ];

      // $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
      //   console.log(' Ticker clicked!', $state)
      //   $state.go('tags.list', { ticker: ticker });
      // }
    }
  });

// Tags module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var tags = angular.module('tags', ['ui.router'])
  tags.config(function($stateProvider) {

    const oldtags = {
      name: 'tags',
      url: '/tags',
      params: {
        ticker: {},
        tag: {}
      },
      // parent: 'tickers',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'tags-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('Tags view $state', $state.params);
            const tags_model = [
              {
                ticker: 'AAPL',
                tags : [{ id: 1, term: 'iPhone 7' }, { id: 2, term: 'iPhone 8' }, { id: 3, term: 'Tim Cook' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'GOOG',
                tags : [{ id: 4, term: 'Pixel' }, { id: 5, term: 'Pixel XL' }, { id: 6, term: 'Chrome Book' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'TWTR',
                tags : [{ id: 7, term: 'tweet' }, { id: 8, term: 'retweet' }, { id: 9, term: 'moments' }]
              }
            ];

            function matchTags(ticker, model) {
              return model.filter(function(obj){
                if (obj.ticker === ticker) { return obj; }
              });
            }

            $scope.tags_model = matchTags($state.params.ticker.ticker, tags_model)[0];

            console.log(' $scope.tags_model', $scope.tags_model)

            $scope.clickTag = function(tag) {
              $state.go('tags', { tag: tag });
            }

            console.log('Tags init', $state.params);
          }
        },
        'list@tags': {

        },
        'view@tags': {
          template: '<view-module ticker="$ctrl.ticker"></view-module>',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('VIEWS view $state');
            $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
          }
        },
        'chart@tags': {
          templateUrl: 'chart-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('CHART view $state');
            $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
          }
        },
        'social@tags': {
          templateUrl: 'social-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('SOCIAL view $state');
            $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    const tags = {
      name: 'container.dashboard.tickers.tagslist',
      url: '/tags',
      params: {
        ticker: {}
      },
      views: {
        'tags' : {
          templateUrl: 'tags-list.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log(' tags-list controller', $state)
            $scope.ticker = $state.params.ticker;

            const tags_model = [
              {
                ticker: 'AAPL',
                tags : [{ id: 1, term: 'iPhone 7' }, { id: 2, term: 'iPhone 8' }, { id: 3, term: 'Tim Cook' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'GOOG',
                tags : [{ id: 4, term: 'Pixel' }, { id: 5, term: 'Pixel XL' }, { id: 6, term: 'Chrome Book' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'TWTR',
                tags : [{ id: 7, term: 'tweet' }, { id: 8, term: 'retweet' }, { id: 9, term: 'moments' }]
              }
            ];

            function matchTags(ticker, model) {
              return model.filter(function(obj){
                if (obj.ticker === ticker) { return obj; }
              });
            }

            $scope.tags_model = matchTags($state.params.ticker.ticker, tags_model)[0];

            console.log(' $scope.tags_model', $scope.tags_model)

            $scope.clickTag = function(tag) {
              $state.go('tags', { tag: tag });
            }
          }
        },
        'view@tags': {
          template: '<view-module ticker="$ctrl.ticker"></view-module>',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('VIEWS view $state');
            $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $stateProvider
      .state(tags);
      // .state(tagslist);
  })
  tags.component('tagsModule', {
    templateUrl: 'tags-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('TAGS component', $state.params);
    }
  });

// ViewHeader module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var view = angular.module('view', ['ui.router'])
  view.component('viewModule', {
    templateUrl: 'view-template.html',
    bindings: {
      ticker: '<'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('VIEW component', $state.params);
      $scope.ticker = this.ticker;
      $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
    }
  });

// Chart module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var chart = angular.module('chart', ['ui.router'])
  chart.component('chartModule', {
    templateUrl: 'chart-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('CHART component', $state.params);
      $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
    }
  });

// Social module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var social = angular.module('social', ['ui.router'])
  social.component('socialModule', {
    templateUrl: 'social-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('SOCIAL component', $state.params);
      $scope.term = $state.params.tag.term;
    }
  });

// TickersApp module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var tickersApp = angular.module('tickersApp', 
  ['ui.router',
   'container',
   'dashboard',
   'tickers',
   'tags',
   'view',
   'chart',
   'social']);

tickersApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

  const login = {
    name: 'login',
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login-template.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'l',
    controller: function($state) {
      this.login = function() {
        $state.go('container.dashboard.tickers', { });
      }
    }
  }

  $stateProvider
    .state(login);
})
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$state',
function($rootScope, $location, $state) {
    // $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
          // console.log(' ')
          // console.log('toState', toState)
          // console.log('state.current.name', $state.current.name)
          // console.log('toParams', toParams)
          // console.log('fromState', fromState)
          // console.log('fromParams', fromParams)
          // console.log('options', options)
      });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log('state.current.name', $state.current.name)
      })

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', 
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){
        console.error('ERROR toState', toState)
        console.error('ERROR fromState', fromState)
      });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound', 
      function(event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams){ 
          console.log('unfoundState.to', unfoundState.to); // "lazy.state"
          // console.log('unfoundState.toParams', unfoundState.toParams); // {a:1, b:2}
          // console.log('unfoundState.options', unfoundState.options); // {inherit:false} + default options
      });

    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', 
      function(event){
        // console.log('viewContentLoaded', event)
      });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have provided, I would say that `ui-router` is doing what it should. You have `tags` state defined so it would populate the unnamed `ui-view`, and it does. When you click on one of the buttons in the `tickers` component, it basically loads the `tags` state instead of the `container` state.

Based on the code you have provided, you have mixed up states and views that should be shown when a specific state is loaded. You are trying to load a `tags` **state** in a `<div ui-view='tags'></div>` placeholder, which represents a placeholder for `tags` **view**, which is a **view** for a specific **state** you want to load. This is not how `ui-router` is supposed to work.

Here is an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/A1EGUhsQRGYxkAoTyvJ7?p=preview) of your modified code. You can see here that I've loaded `dashboard`, `feed`, `tickers` and `tags` views in your `container` state. Although some of them are in separate templates, they are all loaded under the same state.

Since you already have an example how different states are loaded with `login` and `container` state here is an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5tyG17vDAyPXCvXmcr9N?p=preview) of your modified code with a child state. When you click on "Go To Private State" button, it loads the `container.private` state, which is a child state of `container` state. As you can see, `container.private` state has almost the same structure as `container` state. When you click on the button, it will load views defined for `container.private` state in their corresponding placeholders.

I haven't deleted all of unnecessary code, just modified what I've needed. Sorry for that.

From what I can see,  you will have to modify your architecture to just use components and communicate between components with either services, some kind of a pub sub library or try to use `$scope.$emit` and `$scope.$on` if you have a parent-child relationship between your controller.

Comment: I got it working, check the plnkr below! I checked your example, but the tickers didn't load.